# Flex box width different for desktop and mobile

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I'm having a form with some mat-form-fields. Now I've set the width of those items to 750px, but this is of course not correct for a mobile view.

I'm wondering how I can put it the form or mat-form-field that if the page is view on desktop that it should be with a width of 750px, otherwise a width of 100%.

I tried with flex-grow-gt-xs, but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the inputs, you need to set `width: 100%, max-width: 750px;`

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: @Rafie if it's the right answer, don't forget to accept it :]